# ng-options with pre-selected value using ng-model not working

Tags: angularjs

I know there are lots of similar questions all around, but i have no clues why this is not working for me? I want size '4x4' as preselected in the dropdown. '4x4' is now static but finally i will replace '4x4' with a variable that will provide dynamic sizes.

Here is my Controller code:

```
    $scope.sizes = [{
                        size: '4 x 4',
                        price: 1.00  
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 6',
                        price: 5.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 8',
                        price: 7.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 6',
                        price: 9.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 8',
                        price: 10.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '6 x 8',
                        price: 15.00
                    }]

   $scope.selected = {
      "size": '4 x 4'
   }
```

And here is view code:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.size" ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
</select>
```

Comment: How many time you edit the question?

Comment: I just updated my question because i think the answer regarding $scope.sizes[0] works but make 4x4 static , in my snippet i used this for simplification

Comment: If you want it dynamically, then pass the dynamic value to the `ng-model `object. that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $scope.selected = $scope.sizes[0];
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module("App", [])
 .controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.sizes = [{
                        size: '4 x 4',
                        price: 1.00  
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 6',
                        price: 5.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 8',
                        price: 7.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 6',
                        price: 9.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 8',
                        price: 10.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '6 x 8',
                        price: 15.00
                    }]
$scope.selected =    $scope.sizes[0];
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="mainCtrl as keyVar" class="container">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: forgive me for just copied your snippet to my answer :(

Comment: 4x4 is static now but i want to update size using some otherway. $scope.sizes[0]; makes it static. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @NahiduzzamanRose I have update my answer. also here you can update dynamically as  `$scope.selected =   yourdynamicObject;`

Answer (score 2):

I would change the template to

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
</select>
```

and the controller to

```
$scope.selected = $scope.sizes[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Call first object in ng-init `ng-init="selected.size = sizes[0];"` and should initialize `selected` object like `$scope.selected={}`

### Working Demo

```js
angular.module("App", [])
 .controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.sizes = [{
                        size: '4 x 4',
                        price: 1.00  
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 6',
                        price: 5.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 8',
                        price: 7.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 6',
                        price: 9.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 8',
                        price: 10.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '6 x 8',
                        price: 15.00
                    }]
  $scope.selected={};
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="mainCtrl as keyVar" class="container">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.size" ng-init="selected.size = sizes[0];"  ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
</select>
</div>
```

### Update

> '4x4' is now static but finally i will replace '4x4' with a variable that will provide dynamic sizes.

You can create a new scope object (as `YourDynamicObject`) and assign the dynamic value. it will be affect in ng-init

Code like

```
ng-init="selected.size = YourDynamicObject"  // html 

$scope.YourDynamicObject=$scope.size[dynamicindex];//controller
```

Answer (score 0):

**try some thing like this:**

```
  <select ng-init="selected= sizes[0]" 
            ng-model="selected" 
            ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
    </select>
```

Comment: Exactly what is I am answered here :(

Comment: @RameshRajendran so what you moaning about?

Comment: `you have a mistake in your code`. But the code is running successfully on snippet. you can see the result.

Comment: @RameshRajendran not every successfully running code means its correct. You taking it personally

Comment: @RameshRajendran you dont need to do that selected.size = size[0]; if you need get value of size from selected object you will end up writing selected.size.size do you think its right way? wont it cause confusion?

Comment: @RameshRajendran you need to calm down and relax.

Comment: OMG :O . It's a medical miracle.  That's depend on OP variable declaration. if he did `sizes[0].size;` . then the problem will gone.  But thanks for your awareness :) :)

Comment: @RameshRajendran medical miracle will save some body life not code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("App", [])
 .controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.sizes = [{
                        size: '4 x 4',
                        price: 1.00  
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 6',
                        price: 5.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '4 x 8',
                        price: 7.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 6',
                        price: 9.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '5 x 8',
                        price: 10.00
                    },
                    {
                        size: '6 x 8',
                        price: 15.00
                    }]
$scope.selected =    $scope.sizes[0];
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="mainCtrl as keyVar" class="container">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.size for item in sizes">
</select>
  <p>{{selected}}</p>
</div>
```